# Error in coercing R data.frame to a nz.data.frame

Tags: r, netezza

One of the columns in R dataframe has "," (comma) in it and because of it, when I try to convert it into netezza data frame, it throws me below error:

> Error in nzQuery(sqlCommandUpload) : HY008 51 Operation canceled
>   01000 1 Unable to write nzlog/bad files
>   01000 1 Unable to write nzlog/bad files
>   HY000 46 ERROR:  External Table : count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit

How can I achieve this without making any changes to data?

With a dataframe like this, everything works fine:
[image: data frame without ',']

I get error when the dataframe is like this:
[image: Data frame with ',']

```
library(nzr)
library(forecast)
library (reshape2)
library(doBy)
nzDisconnect()
nzConnectDSN('DSNInfo', force=FALSE , verbose=TRUE)


#read file
test2<-read.csv("test_df.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)

# convert to nz dataframe, no error
#nzdf.test2<-as.nz.data.frame(test2)

nzdf.d<-as.nz.data.frame(d)

# copy 
#test<-test2

testd<-d

#replace one of the values containing a ","
#test$Category[1]<-"a,b"

testd$Category[1]<-"Bed, Bath & Towels"

# converting to nz gives error
#nzdf.test<-as.nz.data.frame(test)

nzdf.testd<-as.nz.data.frame(testd)

#remove ","
test$Category <- gsub(",","",test$Category)

# converting to nz dataframe, gives no error
nzdf.test<-as.nz.data.frame(test)
```

Comment: Show your R code and tell us which libraries you are using.

Comment: @ScottMcG edited the question with the required details

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if you have nulls (NAs) in your data? I have faced the same problem but when i checked Netezza-R documentation i found that you can not write Nulls into a Netezza tables from another system. there is a mention about using setOutputNull funciton in such cases.

So a workaround is replace nulls with the string "NULL"  in your R-dataframe, this makes the numerical columns become varchar, mind you. But fortunately "NULL" becomes null in your netezza table automatically. Only extra effort is that you have to covnert the columns back to numeric later.

Hope this helps